# Why won't my Netbeans create a new project?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I've just installed NetBeans 8.2, and all seemed to go well. I did an almost 100% default, except removing one or two modules I would never need, and changing the default workspace the first time it ran.

Now it will do nothing. When I click the `File->New Project` command, nothing at all happens. When I click on several other commands, simply nothing happens at all.

The IDE Log does show a stack trace after I try and create a project. This is that trace:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory starting from ModuleCL@6c9be2b3[org.openide.awt] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@7a1ebcd8, ModuleCL@28e83a83[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.setUpSearch(QuickSearch.java:369)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.<init>(QuickSearch.java:107)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:197)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:125)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.setupSearch(TreeView.java:1936)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.<init>(TreeView.java:1753)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.initializeTree(TreeView.java:299)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:238)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:228)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.BeanTreeView.<init>(BeanTreeView.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesBeanTreeView.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:679)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesPanel.createComponent(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$ExplorerProviderPanel.initGUI(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$ExplorerProviderPanel.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:535)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesPanel.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:719)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesPanel.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:719)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI.initComponents(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:421)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:156)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTemplatePanel.getComponent(ProjectTemplatePanel.java:187)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.createTemplateChooser(NewProjectWizard.java:104)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.templateChooser(TemplateWizard.java:320)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.firstPanel(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:87)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.current(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:144)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.current(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:92)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateStateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:844)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:822)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.updateState(TemplateWizard.java:761)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.updateState(NewProjectWizard.java:84)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor._updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:800)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$200(WizardDescriptor.java:92)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.stateChanged(WizardDescriptor.java:2180)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$Change.stateChanged(WeakListenerImpl.java:356)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.run(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:275)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
SEVERE [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]: Error in RequestProcessor org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.NewProject$1
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory starting from ModuleCL@6c9be2b3[org.openide.awt] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@7a1ebcd8, ModuleCL@28e83a83[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.setUpSearch(QuickSearch.java:369)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.<init>(QuickSearch.java:107)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:197)
    at org.openide.awt.QuickSearch.attach(QuickSearch.java:125)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.setupSearch(TreeView.java:1936)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView$ExplorerTree.<init>(TreeView.java:1753)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.initializeTree(TreeView.java:299)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:238)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView.<init>(TreeView.java:228)
    at org.openide.explorer.view.BeanTreeView.<init>(BeanTreeView.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesBeanTreeView.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:679)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesPanel.createComponent(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:729)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$ExplorerProviderPanel.initGUI(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$ExplorerProviderPanel.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:535)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesPanel.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:719)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI$CategoriesPanel.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:719)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI.initComponents(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:421)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.TemplatesPanelGUI.<init>(TemplatesPanelGUI.java:156)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectTemplatePanel.getComponent(ProjectTemplatePanel.java:187)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.createTemplateChooser(NewProjectWizard.java:104)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.templateChooser(TemplateWizard.java:320)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.firstPanel(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:87)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.current(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:144)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.current(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:92)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateStateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:844)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:822)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.updateState(TemplateWizard.java:761)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.updateState(NewProjectWizard.java:84)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$2.run(TemplateWizard.java:497)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$2.run(TemplateWizard.java:494)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event$1AWTWorker.run(NbMutexEventProvider.java:156)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogParser]: Unpaired license 00000008 without any module.
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
```

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify jdk version. In my case i use next solution:
NetBeans 8.2 is not compatible with jdk 9.
I temporarily renaming the directory jdk-9 and change the default jdkhome at restart.
Or change netbeans_jdkhome in etc\netbeans.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps too.

JDK 9 does not work yet with Netbeans 8.2. You need at least [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?printOnly=1) , [JRE 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).

Open a commandline and type "javac -version" to see the JDK version.

In netbeans, under the tab "tools" choose "java-platforms" and add the JDK 8 as default through "add Platform" (jdk folder). Or try to reinstall netbeans and choose JDK 8 while installing.

Some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909025/how-to-set-default-java-platform-in-netbeans-8-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on) .